# Offline IIS Inetmgr slow to expand server node (2 minutes)...

Tags: windows, performance, iis, windows-server-2008, offline

I've got a couple of IIS servers running Win2k8R2 and IIS 7.5. Whenever I open inetmgr and expand the server node, there is about a 2 minute delay before I can do anything. Once the server node expands, I can perform all tasks normally. I have other offline servers with similar setups which expand the server node near-instantly.

After running a trace using "netsh tracing set trace ... " on the problematic servers, I see that they are trying to reach Microsoft CRL files which would obviously timeout and cause the slowness. On good servers, there is no network trace.

Does anybody have any idea about what would cause this issue and why this slowness is not present on all my servers? I'm guessing some other admin messed up somewhere but finding out where is gonna be a pain.

Here is my trace file for good measure :)

```
15:32:17.684 ::>>>> WinHttp Version 6.0 Build 6.1.7601 >>>>Process InetMgr.exe [912 (0x390)] started at 15:32:17.684 10/07/2014
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpOpen("Microsoft-CryptoAPI/6.1", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY (0), "", "", 0x0)
15:32:17.684 ::winhttp-dll added a reference to winhttp.dll (via LoadLibrary() call)
15:32:17.684 ::thread-pool created
15:32:17.684 ::thread pool initialized successfully
15:32:17.684 ::_SvcsStartup() succeeded; async-count = 1
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpOpen() returning handle 0x1c921c60
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpSetTimeouts(0x1c921c60, 0, 60000, 60000, 60000)
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpSetTimeouts() returning TRUE
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpSetOption(0x1c921c60, WINHTTP_OPTION_CONFIGURE_PASSPORT_AUTH (83), 0x1c86f710 [0x0], 4)
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpSetOption() returning TRUE
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpCrackUrl("http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/disallowedcertstl.cab", 0x0, 0x0, 0x1c86f620)
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpCrackUrl() returning TRUE
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpConnect(0x1c921c60, "ctldl.windowsupdate.com", 80, 0x0)
15:32:17.684 ::Indicate Status 0x1c9e4380, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED (1024), 0x1c86f358 [0x1c9e4380], 8
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpConnect() returning handle 0x1c9e4380
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpOpenRequest(0x1c9e4380, "", "/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/disallowedcertstl.cab?56b780acf368dee0", "", "", 0x1c86f6a0, 0x00000000)
15:32:17.684 ::Indicate Status 0x1ca06060, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED (1024), 0x1c86f308 [0x1ca06060], 8
15:32:17.684 ::WinHttpCreateUrl(0x1c86f240, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1c86f308)
15:32:17.684 ::    WinHttpCreateUrl(); URL = (null), URL Length = 0
15:32:17.699 ::    WinHttpCreateUrl: error 122 [ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER]
15:32:17.699 ::WinHttpCreateUrl() returning FALSE
15:32:17.699 ::WinHttpCreateUrl(0x1c86f240, 0x0, 0x1c94ce00, 0x1c86f308)
15:32:17.699 ::    WinHttpCreateUrl(); URL = http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/disallowe, URL Length = 109
15:32:17.699 ::WinHttpCreateUrl() returning TRUE
15:32:17.699 ::WinHttpOpenRequest() returning handle 0x1ca06060
15:32:17.699 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(0x1c86f408)
15:32:17.699 ::_SvcsStartup() succeeded; async-count = 2
15:32:17.699 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:17.699 ::WPAD: Getting Gateway MACs from Adapter: {*****MASKED*****} ::NextHop.State: ***:**:**.** ::WPAD: Checking Gateway MAC {****MASKED*****}9 ::Identifying Network, using GWMac
15:32:17.699 ::SWPAD lookup key: 00-10-db-ff-10-02
15:32:17.699 ::SWPAD Decision: 2,   (0) OFF, (1) ON, (2) UNKNOWN  (3) OFF_NEED_BROWSE
15:32:17.699 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser() returning TRUE
15:32:17.699 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(0x1c921c60, "http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/disallowedcertstl.cab", 0x1c86f428, 0x1c86f3e0)
15:32:17.699 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:17.699 ::_StartAutoProxyService: The AutoProxy service is already running
15:32:20.262 ::_CallClientGetProxyForUrl the service returned error 12180
15:32:20.262 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl() returning FALSE
15:32:20.262 ::    WinHttpGetProxyForUrl: error 12180 [0x2f94]
15:32:20.262 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(0x1c86e298)
15:32:20.262 ::_SvcsStartup() succeeded; async-count = 2
15:32:20.262 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:20.262 ::WPAD: Getting Gateway MACs from Adapter: {**MASKED**} ::NextHop.State: 515:32:20.262 ::WPAD: Checking Gateway {**MASKED**}::Identifying Network, using GWMac
15:32:20.262 ::SWPAD lookup key: 00-10-db-ff-10-02
15:32:20.262 ::SWPAD Decision: 2,   (0) OFF, (1) ON, (2) UNKNOWN  (3) OFF_NEED_BROWSE
15:32:20.262 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser() returning TRUE
15:32:20.262 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(0x1c921c60, "http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/disallowedcertstl.cab", 0x1c86e2b8, 0x1c86e270)
15:32:22.824 ::_CallClientGetProxyForUrl the service returned error 12180
15:32:22.824 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl() returning FALSE
15:32:22.824 ::    WinHttpGetProxyForUrl: error 12180 [0x2f94]
15:32:22.824 ::WinHttpSetOption(0x1ca06060, WINHTTP_OPTION_AUTOLOGON_POLICY (77), 0x1c86e398 [0x2], 4)
15:32:22.824 ::WinHttpSetOption() returning TRUE
15:32:22.824 ::WinHttpSendRequest(0x1ca06060, "", 0, 0x0, 0, 0, 0)
15:32:22.824 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 transitioning from state _READY to state _SENDING_RECVING
15:32:22.824 ::sys-req updates BytesToSend to 0
15:32:22.824 ::sys-req transitioning from state _INIT to state _SENDING
15:32:22.824 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:22.824 ::sys-sender calling HttpSendHttpRequest(overlapped = 1C9D9350)
15:32:22.824 ::sys-sender transitioning from state  _INIT to state  _SENDING
15:32:22.824 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 received OnDnsResolvingName callback
15:32:22.824 ::sys-req pends send-request
15:32:22.824 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 blocks waiting for async to complete...
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpOpen("Microsoft-CryptoAPI/6.1", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY (0), "", "", 0x0)
15:32:32.637 ::_SvcsStartup() succeeded; async-count = 2
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpOpen() returning handle 0x1c921ee0
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpSetTimeouts(0x1c921ee0, 0, 60000, 60000, 60000)
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpSetTimeouts() returning TRUE
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpSetOption(0x1c921ee0, WINHTTP_OPTION_CONFIGURE_PASSPORT_AUTH (83), 0x1d74f630 [0x0], 4)
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpSetOption() returning TRUE
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpCrackUrl("http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/microsoftrootcert.crl", 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d74f540)
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpCrackUrl() returning TRUE
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpConnect(0x1c921ee0, "crl.microsoft.com", 80, 0x0)
15:32:32.637 ::Indicate Status 0x1c9e44d0, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED (1024), 0x1d74f278 [0x1c9e44d0], 8
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpConnect() returning handle 0x1c9e44d0
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpOpenRequest(0x1c9e44d0, "", "/pki/crl/products/microsoftrootcert.crl", "", "", 0x1d74f5c0, 0x00000000)
15:32:32.637 ::Indicate Status 0x1bf71e30, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED (1024), 0x1d74f228 [0x1bf71e30], 8
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpCreateUrl(0x1d74f160, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d74f228)
15:32:32.637 ::    WinHttpCreateUrl(); URL = (null), URL Length = 0
15:32:32.637 ::    WinHttpCreateUrl: error 122 [ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER]
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpCreateUrl() returning FALSE
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpCreateUrl(0x1d74f160, 0x0, 0x1c99fda0, 0x1d74f228)
15:32:32.637 ::    WinHttpCreateUrl(); URL = http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/microsoftrootcert.crl, URL Length = 63
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpCreateUrl() returning TRUE
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpOpenRequest() returning handle 0x1bf71e30
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(0x1d74f328)
15:32:32.637 ::_SvcsStartup() succeeded; async-count = 3
15:32:32.637 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:32.637 ::WPAD: Getting Gateway MACs from Adapter: {**MASKED**} ::Identifying Network, using GWMac
15:32:32.637 ::SWPAD lookup key: 00-1{**MASKED**}
15:32:32.637 ::SWPAD Decision: 2,   (0) OFF, (1) ON, (2) UNKNOWN  (3) OFF_NEED_BROWSE
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser() returning TRUE
15:32:32.637 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(0x1c921ee0, "http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/microsoftrootcert.crl", 0x1d74f348, 0x1d74f300)
15:32:34.824 ::  <c-b> an async I/O operation completes (overlapped = 1C9D9350, #bytes/info = 0, error = WSANO_DATA (11004))
15:32:34.824 ::sys-sender processing HttpSendHttpRequest completion (error-cdoe = WSANO_DATA (0x2afc), #bytes = 0, overlapped = 1C9D9350)
15:32:34.824 ::sys-sender failed to a request; error = WSANO_DATA (11004)
15:32:34.824 ::ERROR_WINHTTP_FROM_WIN32 mapped (WSANO_DATA) 11004 to (ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) 12007
15:32:34.824 ::sys-req shutting down; send-req encountered fatal error; error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007)
15:32:34.824 ::sys-req completing a send-request call (error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007))
15:32:34.824 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 received OnSendRequest callback; error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007)
15:32:34.824 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 releases sys-req 001C2150
15:32:34.824 ::sys-req failed to cancel the request; the object is already shutting down
15:32:34.824 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 transitioning from state _SENDING_RECVING to state _READY
15:32:34.824 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 signals sync caller 1C9843A0 (api = 5, error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007), # bytes = 0)
15:32:34.824 ::... async completed (result = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007)); usr-req unblocked
15:32:34.824 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 transitioning from state _READY to state _READY
15:32:34.824 ::    WinHttpSendRequest: error 12007 [ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED]
15:32:34.824 ::WinHttpSendRequest() returning FALSE
15:32:34.824 ::WinHttpCloseHandle(0x1ca06060)
15:32:34.824 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 is shutting down
15:32:34.824 ::Indicate Status 0x1ca06060, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING (2048), 0x1c86f350 [0x1ca06060], 8
15:32:34.824 ::WinHttpCloseHandle() returning TRUE
15:32:34.824 ::WinHttpCloseHandle(0x1c9e4380)
15:32:34.824 ::Indicate Status 0x1c9e4380, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING (2048), 0x1c86f350 [0x1c9e4380], 8
15:32:34.824 ::WinHttpCloseHandle() returning TRUE
15:32:34.824 ::WinHttpCloseHandle(0x1c921c60)
15:32:34.824 ::Indicate Status 0x1c921c60, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING (2048), 0x1c86f5d0 [0x1c921c60], 8
15:32:34.824 ::WinHttpCloseHandle() returning TRUE
15:32:35.215 ::_CallClientGetProxyForUrl the service returned error 12180
15:32:35.215 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl() returning FALSE
15:32:35.215 ::    WinHttpGetProxyForUrl: error 12180 [0x2f94]
15:32:35.215 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(0x1d74e1b8)
15:32:35.215 ::_SvcsStartup() succeeded; async-count = 2
15:32:35.215 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:35.215 ::WPAD: Getting Gateway MACs from Adapter: {**MASKED**} ::Identifying Network, using GWMac
15:32:35.215 ::SWPAD lookup key: 00-{**MASKED**}
15:32:35.215 ::SWPAD Decision: 2,   (0) OFF, (1) ON, (2) UNKNOWN  (3) OFF_NEED_BROWSE
15:32:35.215 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser() returning TRUE
15:32:35.215 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(0x1c921ee0, "http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/microsoftrootcert.crl", 0x1d74e1d8, 0x1d74e190)
15:32:37.778 ::_CallClientGetProxyForUrl the service returned error 12180
15:32:37.778 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl() returning FALSE
15:32:37.778 ::    WinHttpGetProxyForUrl: error 12180 [0x2f94]
15:32:37.778 ::WinHttpSetOption(0x1bf71e30, WINHTTP_OPTION_AUTOLOGON_POLICY (77), 0x1d74e2b8 [0x2], 4)
15:32:37.778 ::WinHttpSetOption() returning TRUE
15:32:37.778 ::WinHttpSendRequest(0x1bf71e30, "", 0, 0x0, 0, 0, 0)
15:32:37.778 ::usr-req 1CA0E790 transitioning from state _READY to state _SENDING_RECVING
15:32:37.778 ::sys-req updates BytesToSend to 0
15:32:37.778 ::sys-req transitioning from state _INIT to state _SENDING
15:32:37.778 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:37.778 ::sys-sender calling HttpSendHttpRequest(overlapped = 1C9D9280)
15:32:37.778 ::sys-sender transitioning from state  _INIT to state  _SENDING
15:32:37.778 ::usr-req 1CA0E790 received OnDnsResolvingName callback
15:32:37.778 ::sys-req pends send-request
15:32:37.778 ::usr-req 1CA0E790 blocks waiting for async to complete...
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpOpen("Microsoft-CryptoAPI/6.1", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY (0), "", "", 0x0)
15:32:42.637 ::_SvcsStartup() succeeded; async-count = 2
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpOpen() returning handle 0x1c921da0
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpSetTimeouts(0x1c921da0, 0, 60000, 60000, 60000)
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpSetTimeouts() returning TRUE
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpSetOption(0x1c921da0, WINHTTP_OPTION_CONFIGURE_PASSPORT_AUTH (83), 0x1d86fc60 [0x0], 4)
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpSetOption() returning TRUE
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpCrackUrl("http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/CodeSigPCA.crl", 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d86fb70)
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpCrackUrl() returning TRUE
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpConnect(0x1c921da0, "crl.microsoft.com", 80, 0x0)
15:32:42.637 ::Indicate Status 0x1c9e4380, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED (1024), 0x1d86f8a8 [0x1c9e4380], 8
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpConnect() returning handle 0x1c9e4380
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpOpenRequest(0x1c9e4380, "", "/pki/crl/products/CodeSigPCA.crl", "", "", 0x1d86fbf0, 0x00000000)
15:32:42.637 ::Indicate Status 0x1ca2e3d0, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED (1024), 0x1d86f858 [0x1ca2e3d0], 8
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpCreateUrl(0x1d86f790, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d86f858)
15:32:42.637 ::    WinHttpCreateUrl(); URL = (null), URL Length = 0
15:32:42.637 ::    WinHttpCreateUrl: error 122 [ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER]
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpCreateUrl() returning FALSE
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpCreateUrl(0x1d86f790, 0x0, 0x1c9cba40, 0x1d86f858)
15:32:42.637 ::    WinHttpCreateUrl(); URL = http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/CodeSigPCA.crl, URL Length = 56
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpCreateUrl() returning TRUE
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpOpenRequest() returning handle 0x1ca2e3d0
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(0x1d86f958)
15:32:42.637 ::_SvcsStartup() succeeded; async-count = 3
15:32:42.637 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:42.637 ::WPAD: Getting Gateway MACs from Adapter: {**MASKED**} ::WPAD: Checking Gateway MAC 00-{**MASKED**} ::Identifying Network, using GWMac
15:32:42.637 ::SWPAD lookup key: 00-{**MASKED**}
15:32:42.637 ::SWPAD Decision: 2,   (0) OFF, (1) ON, (2) UNKNOWN  (3) OFF_NEED_BROWSE
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser() returning TRUE
15:32:42.637 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(0x1c921da0, "http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/CodeSigPCA.crl", 0x1d86f978, 0x1d86f930)
15:32:45.199 ::_CallClientGetProxyForUrl the service returned error 12180
15:32:45.199 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl() returning FALSE
15:32:45.199 ::    WinHttpGetProxyForUrl: error 12180 [0x2f94]
15:32:45.199 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(0x1d86e7e8)
15:32:45.199 ::_SvcsStartup() succeeded; async-count = 3
15:32:45.199 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:45.199 ::WPAD: Getting Gateway MACs from Adapter: {**MASKED**} ::NextHop.State: 515:32:45.199 ::WPAD: Checking Gateway MAC 00-{**MASKED**} ::Identifying Network, using GWMac
15:32:45.199 ::SWPAD lookup key: 00-{**MASKED**}
15:32:45.199 ::SWPAD Decision: 2,   (0) OFF, (1) ON, (2) UNKNOWN  (3) OFF_NEED_BROWSE
15:32:45.199 ::WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser() returning TRUE
15:32:45.199 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(0x1c921da0, "http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/CodeSigPCA.crl", 0x1d86e808, 0x1d86e7c0)
15:32:47.762 ::_CallClientGetProxyForUrl the service returned error 12180
15:32:47.762 ::WinHttpGetProxyForUrl() returning FALSE
15:32:47.762 ::    WinHttpGetProxyForUrl: error 12180 [0x2f94]
15:32:47.762 ::WinHttpSetOption(0x1ca2e3d0, WINHTTP_OPTION_AUTOLOGON_POLICY (77), 0x1d86e8e8 [0x2], 4)
15:32:47.762 ::WinHttpSetOption() returning TRUE
15:32:47.762 ::WinHttpSendRequest(0x1ca2e3d0, "", 0, 0x0, 0, 0, 0)
15:32:47.762 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 transitioning from state _READY to state _SENDING_RECVING
15:32:47.762 ::sys-req updates BytesToSend to 0
15:32:47.762 ::sys-req transitioning from state _INIT to state _SENDING
15:32:47.762 ::current thread is not impersonating
15:32:47.762 ::sys-sender calling HttpSendHttpRequest(overlapped = 1C9D9760)
15:32:47.762 ::sys-sender transitioning from state  _INIT to state  _SENDING
15:32:47.762 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 received OnDnsResolvingName callback
15:32:47.762 ::sys-req pends send-request
15:32:47.762 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 blocks waiting for async to complete...
15:32:49.778 ::  <c-b> an async I/O operation completes (overlapped = 1C9D9280, #bytes/info = 0, error = WSANO_DATA (11004))
15:32:49.778 ::sys-sender processing HttpSendHttpRequest completion (error-cdoe = WSANO_DATA (0x2afc), #bytes = 0, overlapped = 1C9D9280)
15:32:49.778 ::sys-sender failed to a request; error = WSANO_DATA (11004)
15:32:49.778 ::ERROR_WINHTTP_FROM_WIN32 mapped (WSANO_DATA) 11004 to (ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) 12007
15:32:49.778 ::sys-req shutting down; send-req encountered fatal error; error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007)
15:32:49.778 ::sys-req completing a send-request call (error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007))
15:32:49.778 ::usr-req 1CA0E790 received OnSendRequest callback; error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007)
15:32:49.778 ::usr-req 1CA0E790 releases sys-req 1CA52CB0
15:32:49.778 ::sys-req failed to cancel the request; the object is already shutting down
15:32:49.778 ::usr-req 1CA0E790 transitioning from state _SENDING_RECVING to state _READY
15:32:49.778 ::usr-req 1CA0E790 signals sync caller 1C984460 (api = 5, error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007), # bytes = 0)
15:32:49.778 ::... async completed (result = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007)); usr-req unblocked
15:32:49.778 ::usr-req 1CA0E790 transitioning from state _READY to state _READY
15:32:49.778 ::    WinHttpSendRequest: error 12007 [ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED]
15:32:49.778 ::WinHttpSendRequest() returning FALSE
15:32:49.778 ::WinHttpCloseHandle(0x1bf71e30)
15:32:49.778 ::usr-req 1CA0E790 is shutting down
15:32:49.778 ::Indicate Status 0x1bf71e30, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING (2048), 0x1d74f270 [0x1bf71e30], 8
15:32:49.778 ::WinHttpCloseHandle() returning TRUE
15:32:49.778 ::WinHttpCloseHandle(0x1c9e44d0)
15:32:49.778 ::Indicate Status 0x1c9e44d0, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING (2048), 0x1d74f270 [0x1c9e44d0], 8
15:32:49.778 ::WinHttpCloseHandle() returning TRUE
15:32:49.778 ::WinHttpCloseHandle(0x1c921ee0)
15:32:49.778 ::Indicate Status 0x1c921ee0, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING (2048), 0x1d74f4f0 [0x1c921ee0], 8
15:32:49.778 ::WinHttpCloseHandle() returning TRUE
15:32:59.762 ::  <c-b> an async I/O operation completes (overlapped = 1C9D9760, #bytes/info = 0, error = WSANO_DATA (11004))
15:32:59.762 ::sys-sender processing HttpSendHttpRequest completion (error-cdoe = WSANO_DATA (0x2afc), #bytes = 0, overlapped = 1C9D9760)
15:32:59.762 ::sys-sender failed to a request; error = WSANO_DATA (11004)
15:32:59.762 ::ERROR_WINHTTP_FROM_WIN32 mapped (WSANO_DATA) 11004 to (ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) 12007
15:32:59.762 ::sys-req shutting down; send-req encountered fatal error; error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007)
15:32:59.762 ::sys-req completing a send-request call (error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007))
15:32:59.762 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 received OnSendRequest callback; error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007)
15:32:59.762 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 releases sys-req 1CA53130
15:32:59.762 ::sys-req failed to cancel the request; the object is already shutting down
15:32:59.762 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 transitioning from state _SENDING_RECVING to state _READY
15:32:59.762 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 signals sync caller 1C9852A0 (api = 5, error = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007), # bytes = 0)
15:32:59.762 ::... async completed (result = ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (12007)); usr-req unblocked
15:32:59.762 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 transitioning from state _READY to state _READY
15:32:59.762 ::    WinHttpSendRequest: error 12007 [ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED]
15:32:59.762 ::WinHttpSendRequest() returning FALSE
15:32:59.762 ::WinHttpCloseHandle(0x1ca2e3d0)
15:32:59.762 ::usr-req 1CA083E0 is shutting down
15:32:59.762 ::Indicate Status 0x1ca2e3d0, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING (2048), 0x1d86f8a0 [0x1ca2e3d0], 8
15:32:59.762 ::WinHttpCloseHandle() returning TRUE
15:32:59.762 ::WinHttpCloseHandle(0x1c9e4380)
15:32:59.762 ::Indicate Status 0x1c9e4380, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING (2048), 0x1d86f8a0 [0x1c9e4380], 8
15:32:59.762 ::WinHttpCloseHandle() returning TRUE
15:32:59.762 ::WinHttpCloseHandle(0x1c921da0)
15:32:59.762 ::winhttp-dll is shutting down
15:32:59.762 ::Indicate Status 0x1c921da0, 0x0, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING (2048), 0x1d86fb20 [0x1c921da0], 8
15:32:59.762 ::WinHttpCloseHandle() returning TRUE
15:33:59.762 ::thread pool is shutting down
15:33:59.762 ::thread pool closed
15:33:59.762 ::thread pool destroyed
15:33:59.762 ::winhttp-dll object released its reference to winhttp.dll via FreeLibrary()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same problem as i described here:
[http://forums.iis.net/t/1222164.aspx?IIS+manager+slow+node+opening](http://forums.iis.net/t/1222164.aspx?IIS%20manager%20slow%20node%20opening)

In my case the server has blocked all outgoing traffic, so it cannot reach the crl servers.

Partially fixed it with Internet options / Connection / LAN Setting and i turned on (Use a proxy server for your LAN) -> localhost:9000. This way the requests are timeouted faster.

The node in IIS Manager opens faster. (7-10s) Before it was (20-30s).

EDIT: Managed to solve the problem with unchecking of
[image]

Comment: I don't handle these servers anymore but I imagine your solution makes sense. I modified the hosts file to have it point to localhost and then that reduced the node expansion to about 10 seconds which was reasonable (compared to 2 minutes ;) ). Thanks!